# $l^1$ no closed in $l^{\infty }$

Tags: functional-analysis

please how show that $l^{1}$ isnt closed subespace of $l^{\infty }$? I think resolving the adherence of $l^{1}$= C but I do not know how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: What about $(1,1/2,1/3,...,1/m,0,0,0,....)$?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $(x_m)$ defined by
$$x_m = (1,1/2,1/3,...,1/m,0,0,...)$$
is in $\ell^1$ for all $m$, but the limit (the harmonic series) is not in $\ell^1$ but definitely in $\ell^\infty$. So $\ell^1$ is not closed in $\ell^\infty$.